# HTTP Header broken? Browsers don't open our pdf, but open all other pdfs

Tags: http-headers, pdf, django, lighttpd

My Firefox and Chrome usually open PDF files very nicely, without asking and within the browser window.

When clicking on a link to a PDF on our own website:

- Firefox asks if it should download them, to see it I need to open the download history.
- Chrome downloads it automatically, but here as well, opening the PDF needs an extra click.

If I copy the PDF to a different Server (Django installation with lighttpd), Firefox and Chrome will display it nicely as usual.

What's wrong?

Comment: You might want to add your sent headers. This is just guessing. Also, this belongs on stackoverflow.com, not here :)

Comment: I'm not migrating this to StackOverflow, it looks appropriate here.   It isn't necessarily a coding question, but it is certainly a webmaster question.

Comment: I think you don't need to convert in your inputStream to charset=UTF-8" for PDF

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to misconfiguration of the server.

Comment: This looks to be off-topic because it requires us to *guess* what could be wrong. There's nothing tangible for us to work with.

Answer (score 3):

See [How to force files to open in browser instead of download (pdf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf) which has an answer from [ColinM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187780/colinm) that tells you exactly what the headers should be:

> To indicate to the browser that the file should be viewed in the browser:
>
> ```
> Content-Type: application/pdf
> Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"
> ```
>
> To have the file downloaded rather than viewed:
>
> ```
> Content-Type: application/pdf
> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"
> ```
>
> EDIT: The quotes around the filename are required if the filename contains special characters such as `filename[1].pdf` which may otherwise break the browser's ability to handle the response.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer. However, I have to accept my own more special one, because that one solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was rather special.

The server had the default mime-type `application/octet-stream` for PDF files. After changing this to `application/pdf` everything worked fine.

In the lighttpd configuration I achieved the change by adding this definition:

```
mimetype.assign += ( ".pdf" => "application/pdf" )
```